# Question on the proof that the Jacquet module preserves admissibility

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

Let $P = MN$ be a parabolic subgroup of a reductive group $G$ over a $p$-adic field.  For $(\pi,V)$ an admissible representation of $G$, the Jacquet module $(\pi_N,V_N)$ is defined by the action of $\pi|_M$ on $V/V(N)$, where $V(N)$ is the linear span of $v - \pi(n)v : v \in V, n \in N$.

I am reading [Casselman's notes](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/research/pdf/p-adic-book.pdf) on representation theory, Theorem 3.3.1/3.3.3, where he shows that $\pi_N$ is admissible.  I am confused on a small detail of the proof which I'll explain.

Let $\overline{N}$ be an opposite unipotent radical of $N$ relative to some minimal parabolic.  Let $K_0$ be a compact open subgroup of $G$ with an Iwahori factorization, $K_0 = \overline{N}_0 \times M_0 \times N_0$, where $M_0 = M \cap K_0$, $N_0 = N \cap K_0$ etc.

Casselman starts the proof with the following (page 36):

> "Let $\bar{U}$ be any finite dimensional subspace of $V_N^{M_0}$, and let $U \subset V^{M_0}$ be any finite dimensional subspace of $V$ mapping onto $\bar{U}$."

It is not clear to me why this is possible.  It is possible if the projection $V^{M_0} \rightarrow V_N^{M_0}$ is surjective.  Is this the case?  If $v + V(N) \in V_N$ is in $V_N^{M_0}$, this means that 
$v - \pi(k)v \in V(N)$ for every $k \in M_0$.  It might be the case $v + V(N)$ has a representative in $V$ which is actually fixed by $M_0$, but I haven't been able to show this.

Comment: Just take any representative and average it over $M_0$ (i.e., apply the canonical projection to the $M_0$-fixed space).

Comment: I'm not sure of the general perspective, but I think that questions like this, that you can answer yourself using standard tools, eventually have to be considered not research-level, even if they are part of understanding research mathematics.  Do you have a nearby community (advisor or whatever) to whom you might be able to pose such questions?  I would consider it perfectly reasonable if a student or colleague asked me this question in person or by e-mail, but I don't think of it as appropriate for MO.  I'm sorry for a personal communication here, but I don't know how to reach you privately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  You're right it's not research level.  I don't know where else to seek help on technical questions like this.  No one at my university knows the nitty gritty details

Comment: You can find my contact information at https://mathematics.tcu.edu/faculty-staff/faculty .  Please feel free to e-mail me.

Comment: Thank you $\space$

Comment: I just realized this also follows from the general result that $V \mapsto V^{M_0}$ is an exact functor for open compact subgroups $M_0$ of $M$.